# Using ssl certificates in node.js request with webpack

Tags: node.js, ssl, webpack, request

I've been hitting an issue on a project that I've been working on that I've just not been able to figure out the correct solution for.

Essentially, my app consumes data from an API, does some processing on that data (to work out averages, differences between different values and so on), and then shows that on a dashboard. The API I am using requires a valid client certificate to be presented, so I'm using `request`'s `cert`, `key` and `ca` options to provide them, pulling the contents of the files in using `fs.readFileSync`.

Initially the dashboard was fairly simple, and I'm trying to improve it by using tools like React; so I've also tried to use Webpack to bundle the code. The problem that I'm hitting, is that when the target in Webpack is set to `web`, it doesn't want to include `fs`, which means I can't load my cert files for `request`, which means I can't query the API I need.

Is there any way around this issue? I've considered separating out the part of the app that queries the api and does the various operations on the data into a separate bundle (with the `server` target) and having that expose its results in JSON format on a `localhost` port for the other half of the app to query, but I'd rather not add that much extra complexity into the app if I can help it.

Here's my function to hit the api:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import rp from 'request-promise';
import getBaseUrl from './baseUrl';
const certFile = '/etc/pki/tls/certs/client_chain.crt';
const keyFile = '/etc/pki/tls/private/client.key';
const caFile = '/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/cloudservicesroot.pem';

const baseUrl = getBaseUrl();

export function getStats(stat, format, sdate, edate) {
  const options = {
    uri: `${baseUrl}${stat}`,
    json: true,
    cert: readFileSync(certFile),
    key: readFileSync(keyFile),
    ca: readFileSync(caFile)
  };

  return rp(options);
}
```

And here is my webpack config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';

export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/webpack-public-path',
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
  ],
  target: 'web',
  externals: {
    fs: {}, //I've tried setting this to various things including true and importing fs and passing as a variable, but it doesn't seem to help
    tls: '{}',
    net: '{}',
    console: '{}'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin){
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true,
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      //here I've got loader rules for jsx, json, fonts, images and css; can add to post if needed
    ]
  }
};
```